# Webpack 5 polyfills

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-5

I am trying to build my project and I keep getting this error.
This happened after adding a new package to my package.json file.
I tried removing and switching to a different package. The error keeps showing up.

csv-parse
csv-parser

I also tried to follow the instructions ad added the webpack.config.js at the root and it did not help me.

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```